# Plotting a PV function graph

Tags: graphics, plot, function

I'm trying to plot the following graph in LaTeX, but I cannot, for the life of me, find mathematical functions that work.
This is my code and the following image is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

```
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\myfirstfunction{(\x - 4.65) / ((\x - 4.65) * (\x + 0.35)) - 0.2}
    \def\mysecondfunction{(\x - 6) / ((\x - 4.65) * (\x + 0.35)) - 0.2}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Volume},
        ylabel={Pression},
        axis lines=middle,
        scaled ticks=false,
        xtick=\empty, % Remove x-axis ticks
        ytick=\empty, % Remove y-axis ticks
        grid=none,
        width=10cm,
        height=8cm,
        xmin=0, % Set x-axis minimum to 0
        xmax=5, % Adjust domain to show only the first quadrant
        ymin=0, % Set y-axis minimum to 0
        ymax=2.5,  % Adjust range to show only the first quadrant
        xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west}, % Place xlabel to the bottom
        ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south east,rotate= 0} % Place ylabel to the left
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0.1:5,samples=100,smooth,blue] {\myfirstfunction}; % Plot function
    \addplot[domain=0.1:5,samples=100,smooth,magenta] {\mysecondfunction}; % Plot second function
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Graph of $y = \frac{x - 4.65}{(x - 4.65)(x + 0.35)} - 0.2$ and $y = \frac{1}{x} + 1$ in the first quadrant}
    \label{fig:graph}
\end{figure}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you don't have particular curves in mind (in this case you'd need to give some more details), start from `\def\myfirstfunction{7.5/(\x+2)}` and  `\def\mysecondfunction{2.5/\x}`. I think the curves are defined by PV=const., i.e., P=const/V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're intermixing `Tikz` and `pgfplots` ?

Here's an approach which draws those curves qualitatively with a high degree of control. Basic ideas:

- just draw lines, where you bend two of them using `to[out=,in=]`
- use self-defined styles to simplify work and code

Let's go through some details. I suggest to look up details in the [pgfmanual](https://tikz.dev/) in parallel.

#### Drawing lines

For example the x-axis starts at (0,0) `\draw[->] (0,0) -- +(8,0);` and moves +(8,0) to the side. It's a relative motion, and in this case there's no difference to using (0,8). However, once your starting point is somewhere else, it's a very nice feature to use.

The option `[->]` simply says: "draw a line between both points, have no symbol for the starting point, and an arrow at its end.

#### Adding text in one go

Tikz follows a path-concept. I.e. you start a path by `\` and end it by a `;` and everything in between are so called actions (*do this!*) .

So extending the previous command into

```
\draw[->] (0,0) -- +(8,0) node[anchor=north,yshift=-3mm]{Volume};
```

means:

- start `\` (what?) to `draw`
- connect points as said before `[->]`
- when reaching the end point (8,0) add a `node`
- instead of referring its position to its center (default) use its upper edge `anchor=north`
- also do some `shifts`
- put some text at its position `{Volume}`
- finally end this path `;`

#### The curves

Two of them are just straight lines, following the same approach as above.

The other two are bend. For easy control you replace the `--` by `to[out=in=]` while specifying suitable angles.

Again for the curves text some nodes are added into the pathes.

#### Styles / formats

Put all you need at the beginning of the `tikzpicture` environment; change only here to change the whole drawing:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},                        % nicer arrow tip
    lw/.style  ={line width=1.5pt},     % line width for all
    isob/.style={dashed,draw=brown,lw}, % reusing line width lw
    isom/.style={dotted,draw=blue,lw},
    adia/.style={green,lw},
    isot/.style={dashed,draw=blue!80!yellow!50,lw},
 ]
```

#### Outlook

Using class `standalone` is useful, as you can generate those drawing separately. In your target document you can use `\includgraphics` from package `graphicx` to include this image as `pdf`, i.e. as vector graphic.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    >={Stealth},                        % nicer arrow tip
    lw/.style  ={line width=1.5pt},     % line width for all
    isob/.style={dashed,draw=brown,lw}, % reusing line width lw
    isom/.style={dotted,draw=blue,lw},
    adia/.style={green,lw},
    isot/.style={dashed,draw=blue!80!yellow!50,lw},
 ]
    % ~~~ a coordinate ~~~~
    \coordinate (A) at (1.5,6.5);
    
    % ~~~ axes ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- +(8,0) node[anchor=north,yshift=-3mm]{Volume};   
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- +(0,8) node[anchor=north east,xshift=-3mm]{Pressure};    
    
    % ~~~ curves ~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[isob] (A) -- +(5,0) node[anchor=south,pos=0.5]{isobaric};     
    \draw[isom] (A) -- +(0,-4.5) node[anchor=south west]{isometric};    
    \draw[adia] (A) to[out=-80,in=160] 
                    +(3,-4.5) node[yshift=7mm,text=black]{adiabatic};   
    \draw[isot] (A) to[out=-60,in=170] 
                    +(4.5,-3) node[text=black,yshift=8mm,xshift=-5mm]{isothermal};  
    
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, this works perfectly like I need it to